# React Native apk installed but not showing in menu

Tags: android, react-native, build, invisible

I'm having some issues trying to install a signed release build on android. I can install my .apk, I can found my app in `Settings -> Applications -> Installed` but it's not showing with the other apps. Also, right at the end of the installation, I can't click on the `OPEN` button.

I can start the app with `react-native run-android` without any problem.

Here I drop my `manifest.xml` :

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.area">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.USE_CREDENTIALS"/>

<application
  android:name=".MainApplication"
  android:label="@string/app_name"
  android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
  android:allowBackup="false"
  android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
  <activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTask"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        <data android:scheme="com.area" android:host="oauth"/>
    </intent-filter>
  </activity>
  <activity android:name="com.facebook.react.devsupport.DevSettingsActivity" />
</application>

</manifest>
```

I found a possible solution by removing the second `<activity />` tag in the manifest but it doesn't work in my case..

Thank in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0):

put

```
        <data android:scheme="com.area" android:host="oauth"/>
```

in another intent-filter like this

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>

        <data android:scheme="com.area" android:host="oauth"/>
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: not working bro